# Why C++ does not move to a 'unversioned model' like HTML/HTML5?

Tags: c++, html, c++11

First, i must say that i write this from the bottom of my dark, envious heart:

After reading this: http://blog.whatwg.org/html-is-the-new-html5

i wonder, what is up that C++ has become so fosilized that they will take 10 years to get a new standard.

I mean, embedded/ancient platforms don't even notice when a new release of the C++ standard come up because guess what? they are constrained by the platform and compiler vendors, so they for the most part, won't be able to take advantage of the new features anyway. So all this weight dragging seems more self-immolation than desire or respect for backward compatibility and such and such

Comment: Other languages move faster because they have less of an installed base.  The more popular a language is, the harder it is to evolve quickly because so many more people are affected.

Comment: Where's the connection between the title and the body? They seem to be entirely different questions.

Answer (score 12):

> i wonder, what is up that C++ has become so fosilized that they will take 10 years to get a new standard.

Wait. How long did it take for HTML to get a new standard, again?

The cases of HTML5 and C++0x are very near parallels. Both take ages to get formalized (both not there, yet), as a consequence both could legally be qualified as vaporware.

But in both cases, nobody cares: the upcoming standards are already mostly implemented in modern browsers/compilers.

So *what exactly* are you complaining about?

Comment: good point. and hey, compiler developers are even slower

Comment: @lurscher: Given that both MSVC 10 and GCC 4.4 (?) implement most of the upcoming C++ standard, I'd say your assertion is pretty much dead wrong.

Comment: It was always the plan to have a long delay from C++ was standardized until the first major update, specifically to give compilers time to mature, and to ensure everyone could get some real-world experience with the language before they discussed how to change it further. Post-C++0x updates should come somewhat faster (committee members have mentioned a ~5-year schedule going forward)

Comment: @jalf: it was never the plan to finalize C++0x after 2009, and I distinctly remember that originally the aim was for a year well *before* 2009.

Comment: true. I simply meant that it was planned to have a delay before beginning work on the next standard. The delay turned out to be quite a bit longer than planned, but it was always the plan to wait roughly a decade, give or take a year or two. Of course the name itself implies they were targeting last decade. :)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond @Konrad's answer, C++ is an ISO standard, and therefore has to deal with all the bureaucratic stuff that all ISO standards require. That takes time. HTML is not an ISO standard, and therefore has a much easier time creating a new standard.

Comment: @nightcracker: W3C is quick to publish standards in comparison to ISO. OTOH, support for W3C's standards lags behind their being published, as opposed to ISO where compilers typically implement things like C++0x features before the standard is officially published.